# Prevent callback execution for dynamically added components in plotly dash

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I have developed a multi-page Plotly Dash application. In my app many UI components are created dynamically. According to the Dash documentation, it is possible to prevent callbacks from being executed when the app is first loaded by setting `prevent_initial_call=True` for specific callbacks. However, this only works if all input and output components are present in the main app layout. When input/output components are created dynamically, the `prevent_initial_call` parameter does not work, and the callbacks are triggered as soon as the components are created. This can make the Dash app slow, as many callbacks are triggered when components are created dynamically.

Is there a workaround to prevent these callbacks from being triggered when dynamically added components are created?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to prevent the callbacks being triggered when you dynamically return markup containing components with ids used in other callbacks.

I can think of two ways to approach this.

**First Approach**

The first approach is to use [`raise PreventUpdate`](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks) in your callbacks so you can prevent unnecesary updates under certain conditions.

Example from the documentation:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Click here to see the content', id='show-secret'),
    html.Div(id='body-div')
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='body-div', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='show-secret', component_property='n_clicks')
)
def update_output(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        return "Elephants are the only animal that can't jump"
```

In the above example the `show-secret` button's `value` property is implicitely set to `None`. The callback doesn't use `prevent_initial_call=True` so it will run immediately, but it uses the fact that `n_clicks` is `None` to determine that the button has not been clicked before.

You could use the same principle in your own callbacks. Based on the (default) value(s) of your input(s) you can decide if the rest of the code in your callbacks needs to be run.

**Second Approach**

You could put the markup for your pages in the layout, but hide the pages you don't want to show based on the url using css (With `display: none` for example). If you go with this approach you can prevent the callbacks being triggered. The disadvantage of this is that pages are in the layout and you might not want that.

Comment: I am currently using the first approach you described, where the raise PreventUpdate parameter is used to prevent updates of unnecessary outputs. However, with this approach, even if the output is not updated, the callback is still triggered. If there are many callbacks connected to dynamically added components, this can slow down the performance of the application, as all the callbacks are fired.

Comment: How many callbacks do you have? Are you sure it's just the callbacks being fired that's slowing your application down?

Comment: I am developing a multipage Dash app where I create numerous dynamic components based on user actions across different pages. However, I am experiencing slow performance, particularly during app start-up, where the app displays the "Loading..." message in the top left corner of the screen.

Comment: Could the reason for this be that I am using a large number of callbacks in my app?

Comment: Is it slow for all pages when you reload? I would investigate what's actually causing the slow performance before you try to optimise the standard callback behavior of dash.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The app is experiencing slow performance, particularly during start-up. One possible reason for this is that as the app's functionality grows and more callbacks are used, it can affect the loading time of the Dash app. Additionally, the triggering of callbacks for dynamic elements can also have an impact on performance.